# Add MGSplitViewController to simple project

Tags: objective-c, integration, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I'm trying to use that MGSplitViewController ([already mentioned here, but some one told me I have to ask a new question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949573/mgsplitviewcontroller-not-as-root)), because some ideas will have one or more splitviews and Apple's reviews are not that easy to pass, so I thought I just use some time to test some existing frameworks, like the MGSplitViewController.

But I don't get it working for about 4 long and hard days(and some nights, too ;) ) - any help would really be really great!!!

My problem is the following:

I have just a simple start view with a segmented control. after the launch and some checks I would like to load the splitview in that simple view. I'm using the storyboard for the simple view and I added the xibs from the example (because I had no idea how to integrate them in the storyboard as well - seems to be the next topic, I'll take a look at...)

Sounds very easy, but with the commented header file and the demo project I'm absolutely not able to reproduce it for a non root controller loading...

I have packed the source code for better understanding, downloadable at
http://www.file-upload.net/download-3866273/mgsplittest.zip.html
.

If any one can help me with this, correcting the project, this would be really, really, really great!!!

Greetings,
matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue -

FORGET MGSplitViewController :)

Write it your own, really not difficulty:

- need two views(navigation_left_sided, detailsview_right_sided) in the YOURSPLITVIEWController in the storyboard
- all detailviews should be build with xibs, in storyboard I have not found a way doing this in a clean way (any tipps appreciated)
- the leftsided view delegates calls/view loadings to the other
- load your detailview controller and display
- finished ;)

It is also a good training to work with delegates, observer and asynchronous dispatching. At the time I asked the question, I have not worked much with them - blame on me ;)

Advantage of writting your own:
 - reusable
 - fully customizable
 - in portrait mode also visible, you can just change the sizes of both
 - custom animations for changing the detailsview (move details from bottom to top or curl or anything)
 - after this you have a lot of basic knowledge like delegates, etc... (it was in my case)

Or use the iOS6 feature for grids also very simple, but iOS6 based devices only...

That's it, very easy :)

Any questions? Just ask :D

But I have written the code for my company, so I cannot share, just answering questions and giving you the tipps from above ;)

Greetings,
matthias

Comment: So interesting how to write own SplitView. Can you give some small example? There is only one future that I need - the MasterView's width. Because default 320 is very uncomfortable for my app. Thanks

Comment: Hi Romowski,
right now I'm very busy, but I promise to add example code in the next days/week - I hope this is ok? ;)